# SQL Query to sum item locations

Tags: sql

I have a database with multiple warehouses and multiple locations under that. I am trying to sum the three locations into one within a SQL query. I have the following query currently. I'm not understanding why the results do not actually sum.

```
/*qty on hand*/
SELECT
item
, loc
, sum (qty_on_hand)
FROM         itemloc
WHERE (whse = N'MAIN') AND (item = N'011021')
GROUP BY item
        , whse
        , loc
        , unit_cost
        , qty_on_hand
```

My results show as this:

| item | loc | qty_on_hand |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 011021 | PROD | -8391.0 |
| 011021 | STOCK | 1000.0 |

Comment: *I'm not understanding why the results do not actually sum* I can't see any `sum`, what results are you expecting?

Comment: hi Justin, you'll need to be precise with what relational database management system you're using and perhaps expand on your operation with a sample of your input data. From my first pass at your code - the values aren't aggregating because you're not calling a an aggregation method i.e `select sum(value), id from tbl group by id`

Comment: Often a query that wants to sum things has `SUM()`.  Or at least `+`.

Comment: I posted the wrong darn query. I updated it.

Comment: If you want a single sum() for all location, drop location from GROUP BY list

Comment: You're grouping by `loc` and you have 2 groups, what would you expect to see in the `loc` column?

Comment: If I remove `loc` from the group by, it gives me an error stating `loc` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Of course it does - the server doesn't know what to do with the *two distinct values you have*. What would *you* do?

Comment: Just change your group by to `GROUP BY item, loc` it should work. Provided that you want the sum to be based on those two fields

Comment: I want to combine them into one column showing the total in the warehouse.

Comment: So you want to combine the total of PROD and STOCK ? just change the query to not select `loc` and remove it from the group by as well.